# JQM: On using <pre> tag in Jquery Mobile app, the formatting disappears on viewing through mobile device

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, pre

I am trying to display a text containing multiple paragraphs, and multiple blank lines between paragraphs, all enclosed within `<pre>` tag.

It works fine when I view it through PC browser (Chrome). However after installing the app on a mobile, the same page looses its formatting.

Can anyone please help me out with a solution? Even a small headway will help.

This is the screen capture from my mobile device

[image]

Whereas I wanted to view the data in the following format. Below is the image from my PC Crome

[image]

Comment: could you provide some screenshots? The pc version and the mobile version.

Comment: Hi Alkis, I have added some screenshots. First one from my mobile device and the second one from my PC. I am using Samsung S Duos with Android 4.0.4

Comment: Are you sure that jqm is loaded correctly when that page is being shown?

Comment: Yes, it is getting loaded correctly. I wanted to add one peace of information. The whole content is part of a listview i.e. li tag. Will that create any problem?

Comment: Is it dynamic? If yes, then it might.

Comment: Yes it is dynamic, However I am refreshing the listview $("#Content").listview().listview("refresh")

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference but it should be $("#Content").listview("refresh")

Comment: Could you post your markup after being generated?

Comment: I want to take this up again. Can someone please help me out. I am still struggling with this issue